# AAPT2 Gradle build error after updating to Android Studio 3.5 (and Gradle 3.5.0)

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, aapt2

Have updated Studio to 3.5 (from 3.1).
Gradle upgraded to 3.5.0  (before was 3.1.2 in project).

On building got error: "Unsupported operating system."  (before updating project building was without errors)

System is "Linux Mint 4.4.0-112-generic #135~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 23 20:41:48 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
"

I tried: Download SDK anew, reboot system, install [libs](https://developer.android.com/studio/install#64bit-libs)
..... same error

UPD: fixed by downgrading Gradle, but anyway is there any solutions for new versions?

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'
... 3 more

Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$MultipleTaskActionFailures: Multiple task action failures occurred
... 35 more

Caused by: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
... 80 more

Caused by: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.5.0-5435860-linux Daemon #0: AAPT2 is not supported on 32-bit Linux, see supported systems on https://developer.android.com/studio#system-requirements-a-namerequirementsa

at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Daemon.handleError(Aapt2Daemon.kt:162)
at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Daemon.checkStarted(Aapt2Daemon.kt:57)
at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Daemon.compile(Aapt2Daemon.kt:91)
at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonManager$LeasedAaptDaemon.compile(Aapt2DaemonManager.kt:169)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileRunnable$run$1.invoke(Aapt2CompileRunnable.kt:38)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileRunnable$run$1.invoke(Aapt2CompileRunnable.kt:29)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.namespaced.Aapt2DaemonManagerService.useAaptDaemon(Aapt2DaemonManagerService.kt:66)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.namespaced.Aapt2DaemonManagerService.useAaptDaemon$default(Aapt2DaemonManagerService.kt:64)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileRunnable.run(Aapt2CompileRunnable.kt:35)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade.run(Workers.kt:335)
... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unsupported operating system.
at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Daemon.checkStarted(Aapt2Daemon.kt:60)
... 29 more
```

Comment: Can you run in a java program and get the output of System.getProperty("os.arch") ?

Comment: @IzabelaOrlowska, i386

Comment: Please try with 3.6 alpha 12 - it should have a fix for it now :)

Comment: A fix on an alpha version is not really viable for most people.  I'm encountering this issue as well, and we will not be using an alpha version of the gradle plugin.

Comment: Have got update with Gradle 3.6.0, the problem disappeared. Thanks! =)

Answer (score 0):

> AAPT2 aapt2-3.5.0-5435860-linux Daemon #0: AAPT2 is not supported on 32-bit Linux, see supported systems on https://developer.android.com/studio#system-requirements-a-namerequirementsa

from your error log, `AAPT2 is not supported on 32-bit Linux`, you need reinstall a 64-bit Linux System

Comment: getconf LONG_BIT  --> 64  ;  
uname -i --> x86_64 ;  
It is already 64-bit

Comment: all installed JRE on system are "64-Bit Server VM" too

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using java 32 bits by mistake. Downloaded jdk x64 and everything worked again.